# Add Payment source to Stripe with firebase-cloud-functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe payment with my firestore firebase database. I'm having trouble figuring out add payment source function given in the firebase doc example. What am I missing here?

```
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.firestore
.document('Customers/{userId}/paymentSources/{paymentId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    let newPaymentSource = change.after.data();
    if (newPaymentSource === null){
        return null;
    }
    return admin.firestore().collection("Customers").doc(`${context.params.userId}`).get('customer_id')
        .then((snapshot) => {
          return snapshot.val();
        }).then((customer) => {
          return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {newPaymentSource});
        }).then((response) => {
          return change.after.ref.parent.set(response);
        }, (error) => {
          return change.after.ref.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
        }).then(() => {
          return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
        });
   });
```

I tried

```
console.log(snapshot.val())
```

and it gives me a type error.

[Firestore database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJXo2.png)

[Error Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVMho.png)

Comment: Please do not include images and links in questions - links break and if we want to re-use you structure in an answer we would have to retype it. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading from Cloud Firestore, yet are using variable names and method calls that are for the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and have different APIs.

The equivalent code for Firestore would be:

```
return admin.firestore().collection("Customers").doc(`${context.params.userId}`).get()
    .then((doc) => {
      return doc.data();
    }).then((customer) => {
      ...
```

Also see:

- the documentation on [reading a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: Thank you! It's definitely the difference of using firestore and RTDB